# Validation using Jquery/$.ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with radios and trying to validate starting with jq/$.ajax and then posting info in php.

form.php

```
<tr>
  <td class="h"><span class="txt_wht">t1</span></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="gm[0]" value="t1" />
  <td class="vs"><span class="txt_yel_sm">vs</span></td>
  <td class="a"><span class="txt_wht">t2</span></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="gm[1]" value="t2" />

  <td><input type="radio" name="g1" value="a" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="g1" value="b" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="g1" value="c" /></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td class="h"><span class="txt_wht">t1</span></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="gm[0]" value="t1" />
  <td class="vs"><span class="txt_yel_sm">vs</span></td>
  <td class="a"><span class="txt_wht">t2</span></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="gm[1]" value="t2" />

  <td><input type="radio" name="g2" value="a" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="g2" value="b" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="g2" value="c" /></td>
 </tr>
```

validade.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //global vars

    form.submit(function () {
        if (validate1() && validate2()) {
            //vars
            var exst_email = $('#exst_email').attr('value');
            var g1 = $("input[name='g1']:checked").attr('value');
            //more vars

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "scripts/sbmt.php",
                data: "exst_email=" + exst_email,
                success: function (exst_rsp) {

                    //if its not exist
                    if (exst_rsp == "not_exist") {
                        valInfo.text("Error1!");
                        valInfo.addClass("error");
                        email_reg_err = true;
                    } else {
                        valInfo.text("");
                        valInfo.removeClass("error");
                        email_reg_err = false;
                    }
                    //more validation with error msgs

                    //validate 1 & validate 2 functions
```

and sbmt.php

```
session_start();
// connect to db
require_once('conn.php');

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT email FROM table WHERE email=?')){
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['exst_email']); 
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();

   $numRows = $stmt->num_rows();
   if($numRows < 1){
       echo 'not_exist';
       exit();
   }
   $stmt->close();
}
//more validation
```

Now,

1. Due to Dreamweaver, I know that I don't have typing errors or unclosed tags.
2. My validate 1 & 2 functions are working fine.
3. Due to firebug,

   a) I know that my data are posted in sbmt.php

   b) **I get no response back to display the error msg.**

I am validating 3 more forms (textareas only if it matters) using the exact same way (differentjs/php files) and they are working fine!

Any suggestion on what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I don't know why but here's the fix:

I wasn't passing to sbmt.php the `<input type="hidden">` values since I **didn't use** them at the moment.

But I desided to post them as well to see if it does any good. And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Within you submit function you can try:

```
form.submit(function(e){

   e.preventDefault(); // to prevent the form from submitting itself

  // you all validation code

});
```

### Note

I think `$_POST['email']` in your `PHP` code should be `$_POST['exst_email']`, because your posted data in `AJAX` contains key as `exst_email` here `data: "exst_email="+ exst_email,`
 but not `email`.

So, if you `PHP` is right then you should send data as `data: "email="+ exst_email`

Comment: @Pavlos1316 that means you want to do it for one particular form?

Comment: yes... my other forms as I wrote are geting validated and working fine the same way but using different js/php files (using the same coding philosophy)

Comment: It is just a typing mistake here :( I've been checking my code typing 3 days now just because I know the other forms work

Comment: e.preventDefault(); does no difference.